# First derivative bounded by supremum of difference of values in disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Need a little help in the following:

Let $f(z)$ analytic function on $D = \{z\in\mathbb C: |z| < 1\}$. Define $\displaystyle d = \sup_{z,w \in D} |f(z) - f(w)|$.

Prove that $|f'(0)| \leq \frac{d}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint(s):

1. Put $g(z)=f(z)-f(-z)$. What is the link between $g'(0)$ and $f'(0)$?
2. Apply the Cauchy integral formula to the circle $C(0,r)$ for $0<r<1$ to get $|g'(0)|\leq \frac dr$.
3. Conclude.

Note that $\frac 12$ is the best constant we can hope; take $f(z)=z$ to see that, and you can, by the same method, get a bound for the odd derivatives at $0$.

Comment: Could you write for me explicitly the step $2$? Please, $g(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{g(z)}{z}dz$ am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Hence $g'(0)=\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{\{|z|=r\}}\frac{g(z)}{z^2}dz$, and $|g(z)|\leqslant d$.

Comment: Please tell me for which type of functions the equality holds, that is, $2|f'(0)|=d$. Actually, I am guessing that equality holds when f is linear, but can't prove it.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo How is $g'(0)$ equal to the quantity described above? What is $\frac{d}{dz} \int_{|z|=r } \frac{g(z)}{z} dz$? Can you take the derivative inside? g(z) is also a function of z. Actually I see it. Thank you