# Analytic function on unit disk - bounded derivative of origen

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f(z)$ be an analytic function on unit disk $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$.

$$d=\sup_{w,z\in D}|f(w)-f(z)|.$$

prove:

$$|f'(0)|<\frac d 2.$$

Comment: If $f(z)=z$ for all $z\in D$, then $f'(0)=d/2$ exactly. Maybe that is the only exception to strict inequality. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Can one show that the supremum is actually attained and that the points $w,z$ at which it is attained are on the boundary? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If $|f'(0)|$ were bigger than $d/2$, then $|f'(z)|$ would have to diminish as one moves toward the boundary, lest values of $f(z)$ change too fast so that they differ by more than $d/2$ from what they are at other locations.  But that would mean the maximum of $|f'(z)|$ is not on the boundary, and we can't have that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Yanay Tevet please look here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111809/inequality-relating-diameter-of-the-image-of-a-holomorphic-function-on-the-unit