# Relation between diameter of a holomorphic function defined on the unit disc and it's derivative at 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

following question has been discussed before, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111809/inequality-relating-diameter-of-the-image-of-a-holomorphic-function-on-the-unit) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111809/inequality-relating-diameter-of-the-image-of-a-holomorphic-function-on-the-unit).
For 2 reasons I ask this again: 
$1.$I have solved this question in an other way but the solution doesn't seem to be correct and I'm wondering where am I missing.
$2.$What are the conditions needed to equality holds?

> let f be a holomorphic function on the unit disc.Define $d=sup_{z,w∈D}|f(z)−f(w)|$.
> show that $|f^{'}(0)| \leq \frac{d}{2}$

My solution is as follows:
for any two ponts $z,w$ let $C_r$denote a circle with radius r centered at 0 s.t $|z|,|w| < r$
$$|f^{'}(0)|= \frac{1}{2\pi}|\oint_{C_r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^2}d\zeta| \le \frac{1}{2\pi}|\oint_{C_r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)(\zeta-w)}d\zeta| \le
\frac{1}{4\pi}|\oint_{C_r}\frac{f(\zeta)(z-w)}{(\zeta-z)(\zeta-w)}d\zeta| \le$$
$$\frac{1}{2}|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)}d\zeta - \frac{1}{2\pi i}|\oint_{C_r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-w)}d\zeta| = \frac{1}{2}|f(z)-f(w)|$$
and by taking the $sup$ from both sides conclusion yields. But I guess my solution is wrong. Where am I missing?

Also what are the conditions on f so that equality holds?(obviously equality holds for linear functions, are these the only functions? if yes how should I prove this.

Comment: How do you get the first inequality?

Comment: since both z,w are closer to center than radius.

Comment: It does not hold $|\zeta|\ge |\zeta-z|$ for any $\zeta$ in general, and even if it does, your inequality need not be true; the absolute value should go inside.