# intuition behind one of the steps in proving Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Riemann mapping theorem is a well-known theorem in complex analysis which states:

> Any simply connected open set $U$ $\subset \mathbb{C}$ conformally equivalent with the unit disc $D$, namely there is a holomorphic bijection $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

proof of this theorem consists of several steps which I can manage to some how make sense of them except of step  is that we try to maximize $f^{'}(0)$ among all holomorphic injective functions from $U$ to $\mathbb{C}$.
intuitively, I can see that by making $f^{'}(0)$ bigger we manage to cover more of the disc and we're closer to being surjective but I don't know how to make this rigor.
For example one can manage to make relation between $f^{'}(0)$ and the diameter of the image in some cases but still the realtion is'nt clear to me.(to read more on this see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111809/inequality-relating-diameter-of-the-image-of-a-holomorphic-function-on-the-unit) for example).

Comment: The intuition you already have seems reasonable to me. $f$'s behaviour is dominated by $f'(0)$ in $f(z)=f(0) + f'(0)z + O(z^2)$ for $z$ small

Comment: this is related to the notion of conformal radius at a point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_radius