# Given bounds on analytic function, finding bounds on its derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be analytic on $\Delta$ (unit disc) and satisfy $|f| < 1$. Prove that if $f( \frac{1}{2} ) = f(-\frac{1}{2} ) = 0$, then $|f^{\prime}(0)| \leq \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: So, I tried to find the power series expansion of $f=\sum_k a_kz^k$ around 0 at $1/2$ and $-1/2$. I got $\sum_k a_k 2^{-k}=\sum_k (-1)^k a_k 2^{-k}$. I am fairly sure I can't conclude that $f$ is an even function from this. Is there any way I can show $0$ maps to $0$, because then I think I can show the result.

Comment: [This problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81649/first-derivative-bounded-by-supremum-of-difference-of-values-in-disc) is similar in some ways.

Comment: Hint: 3 applications of the Schwarz Lemma

Comment: @zokomoko To which disks do you intend to apply Schwarz's lemma?

Answer (score 1):

So, I think I have a solution:
We can factor $f(z)=\frac{z-1/2}{1-1/2 z} \cdot \frac{z+1/2}{1+1/2 z} \cdot f_1(z)$ where $f_1(z)$ is holomorphic; (like Blaschke factorization except that $f_1(z)$ may have other zeroes). Using a limiting argument, we can conclude that $|f_1(z)|\leq 1$ on $|z|=1$. Using Cauchy integral estimates we have $|f_1^{\prime}(0)|\leq 1$.
Differentiating $f(z)=\frac{z-1/2}{1-1/2 z} \cdot \frac{z+1/2}{1+1/2 z} \cdot f_1(z)$ and plugging our estimates for $z=0$, gives us the desired result.

Comment: (+1) This looks like the right way to do it. You could use Schwarz's lemma on $f_1$ to show $\lvert f_1'(0) \rvert <1$, rather than estimating integrals, which looks a bit cleaner. Well done, this was a tough one.

Comment: Hmm.. but do I know 0$\mapsto 0$? If I do, then I can use Schwarz, else I might have to work extra i think?

Comment: Ooh, good point...