# Let $f$ be analytic on $B_1(0)$ and $\vert f(z) \vert \leq 1$ for $\vert z \vert <1$, show $\vert f'(0) \vert \leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on $B_1(0)$ and suppose $\vert f(z) \vert \leq 1$ for $\vert z \vert < 1$. Show $\vert f'(0) \vert \leq 1$.

So by a Corollary of Cauchy's Theorem I have that

$$f^{(1)}(0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the unit circle, Thus we have

\begin{align}
\vert f'(0) \vert &\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \vert \frac{f(z)}{z^2} \vert \vert dz \vert \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2} \vert dz \vert \\
&= 1
\end{align}

and therefore $\vert f'(0) \vert \leq 1$. Is this solution correct? In the last equality I used the fact that $\int_\gamma \vert e^{i n t} \vert dt=2 \pi$.

Comment: To make your inequality you have to use $\int|e^{int}|dt=2\pi$, also need absolute value sign for $2\pi i$ in front.

Comment: oh shoot, you're right @Yuval

Comment: but isn't $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}>0$ @Yuval

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' This expression is meaningless, as the complex numbers are not well ordered

Comment: that's right, good catch @GBA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you don't necessarily know that $f$ is defined on the boundary, which you used in your calculations. We let $\gamma_\varepsilon$ be the circle with radius $1-\varepsilon$. The inequality then becomes: \begin{align}
\vert f'(0) \vert &\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} \vert \frac{f(z)}{z^2} \vert dz \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{|z^2|}  dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} 1dz \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-\varepsilon)^2}
\end{align}
Since this is true for every $\varepsilon>0,$ we see that:
$$|f'(0)|\leq \frac{1}{(1-\varepsilon)^2}\to1$$ And finally $$|f'(0)|\leq 1$$
Obviously, $|f'(0)|$ doesn't necessarily have to be equal to $0$, for example $f(z)=z$.

Comment: You can also just note that the values on the boundary are meaningless as it is a measure 0 set, but that may be beyond the level of this course.

Comment: @Alan This is true but I kept it with the line the OP chose

Comment: so if we invoke a bit of measure theory, we need not look at the boundary @Alan as the boundary is a set of measure zero?

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' Correct,  the contributions to the integral are 0 regardless of the values.

Comment: The function need not even be defined on the boundary. I think it may be that it is unable to be extended continuously to the boundary. The limiting argument should let $\gamma$ be the circle of radius $1 - \varepsilon$, and then let $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: The asker should be interested by [this generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81649/305862)

Comment: @Mason You're right, fixed it.